# jQuery Datepicker toggle between range selection and single date selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

- I'm using Datepicker to toggle between date selection for oneway and round bus trips.
- Function `datecalendar` is for round and initiated from round div, while `datecalendar1` is for oneway and is initiated from "from" div.
- Both functions execute properly on first instance.
- However if I first select any function say `datecalendar1` for oneway it works fine but then after selection if i click on return div (to which onclick `datecalendar` for range selection is attached) then still Datepicker is initiated with single date selection and not range as in `datecalendar` function appended to onclick.

  ```
         <script type="text/javascript">
        function datecalendar () {
          $.datepicker._clearDate('#datesearchdiv');
           $.datepicker._defaults.onAfterUpdate = null;


     var datepicker__updateDatepicker = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
          datepicker__updateDatepicker.call(this, inst);

            var onAfterUpdate = this._get(inst, 'onAfterUpdate');
               if (onAfterUpdate) onAfterUpdate.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [(inst.input ? inst.input.val() : ''), inst]);
         }


             $(function() {

           var cur = -1,
           prv = -1;
            $('#datesearchdiv')
  .datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [12, 1],
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,


    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      return [true, ((date.getTime() >= Math.min(prv, cur) && date.getTime() <= Math.max(prv, cur)) ? 'date-range-selected' : '')];
    },

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var d1, d2;

      prv = cur;
      cur = (new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay)).getTime();
      if (prv == -1 || prv == cur) {
        prv = cur;
        $('#departdate').val(dateText);
      } else {
        d1 = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(Math.min(prv, cur)), {});
        d2 = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(Math.max(prv, cur)), {});
        var d11 = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(Math.min(prv, cur)), {});
        var d22 = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(Math.max(prv, cur)), {});
        $('#departdate').val(d1);
        $('#returndate').val(d2);
        spandateupdate(d11, d22);
      }
    },

    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
      //prv = cur = -1;
    },


  })
  .position({
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left bottom',
    of: $('#departdate')
  })
  .hide();

              $('#departdate').on('focus', function(e) {
  var v = this.value,
    d;

  try {
    if (v.indexOf(' - ') > -1) {
      d = v.split(' - ');

      prv = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', d[0]).getTime();
      cur = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', d[1]).getTime();

    } else if (v.length > 0) {
      prv = cur = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', v).getTime();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    cur = prv = -1;
  }

  if (cur > -1) $('#datesearchdiv').datepicker('setDate', new Date(cur));

  $('#datesearchdiv').datepicker('refresh').show();
         showdatespan();

       });

        });

         document.getElementById("departdate").focus();
         document.getElementById("departdate").select();
            }
                </script>
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                        function datecalendar1 () {
                    $.datepicker._defaults.onAfterUpdate = null;


        var datepicker__updateDatepicker = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
             $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
       datepicker__updateDatepicker.call(this, inst);

      var onAfterUpdate = this._get(inst, 'onAfterUpdate');
           if (onAfterUpdate) onAfterUpdate.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] :    null), [(inst.input ? inst.input.val() : ''), inst]);
        }


         $(function() {

          var cur = -1,
                prv = -1;
            $('#datesearchdiv')
  .datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [12, 1],
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,


    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      return [true, ((date.getTime() === Math.min(cur)) ? 'date-range-selected' : '')];
    },

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var d1;

      prv = cur;
      cur = (new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay)).getTime();
      if (prv == -1 || prv == cur) {
        prv = cur;
        $('#departdate').val(dateText);
      } else {
        d1 = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(Math.min( cur)), {});
        var d11 = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(Math.min( cur)), {});
        $('#departdate').val(d1);
        spandateupdate1(d11);
      }
    },

    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
      //prv = cur = -1;
    },


  })
  .position({
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left bottom',
    of: $('#departdate')
  })
  .hide();

         $('#departdate').on('focus', function(e) {
  var v = this.value,
    d;

  try {
    if (v.indexOf(' - ') > -1) {
      d = v.split(' - ');

      prv = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', d[0]).getTime();
      cur = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', d[1]).getTime();

    } else if (v.length > 0) {
      prv = cur = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', v).getTime();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    cur = prv = -1;
  }

  if (cur > -1) $('#datesearchdiv').datepicker('setDate', new Date(cur));

  $('#datesearchdiv').datepicker('refresh').show();
  showdatespan();

    });

      });
       document.getElementById("departdate").focus();
       document.getElementById("departdate").select();
     }
          </script>
  ```